# List reference issue c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have a list say `listOriginal` and am storing it in Viewstate..

```
ViewState["Origion"] = listPatientEncounter;
```

now,I need to do some formatting in the list items and save it on another Viewstate for further usage..

```
 List<....> listCopy = new List<....>();
 listCopy= (from n in listOriginal select n).ToList();

 //This method formattes a few listCopy items
   ViewState["copylist"] = ConverttoUTCTime(listCopy);
```

But,the problem is that the changes made in second list also shows op on the first list due to which I am getting problems where I want to use `ViewState["Origion"]` which has items in it's origional state..

Comment: I would store them in the Session instead(even better, don't store them at all but retrieve them from database always). Because ViewState must be serialized and will be sent to the client and back to server so it wastes bandwidtht. Session won't cause additional traffic and serialization since the variable  is stored in memory(by default).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If item of list is an object, than you changed properties of a source object.
.ToList() is creating new list object and it is not cloning the items.

In another words it will be the "another" list with the same items.

To resolve the issue you should clone list items.

Answer (score 3):

Objects will be passed  by ref, you will need to copy the data inside the list to the second list, you cant use the .ToList().

You need to clone the items insisde your original list, and add them to the second one, you can manually copy values or use the Clone() if its available.

Comment: would you plz elaborate a little...I am already copying items from the original list to listCopy and am then applying toList() method also..!!

Answer (score 2):

This because (most probably) at least according to the result you get, it the **content** of your list is a `reference type`.

Having reference type filled inside one instance of the list and moved into another does not make it *another* instance. It cotinues to be (yes different pointer, but..) pointing to the same memory location. So the different lists elements points to the same location, so the changes made by one are visible by another.

To resolve this issue, one of possible solutions is creating a clone of your object, or at least, only those objects that you're going to change, if the change **has not be affected in original collection** by software architecture. This is just an idea, you should pick a solution that fits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using in-process Session state, the 2 lists are actually referencing the same instance of the list. You would need to clone your list in order to truely have 2 distinct lists.

Now, if you were using SQL session management, this would essentially end up performing the cloning for you, and they would be distinct since it would be serializing/deserializing the objects to a database.